# MikroTik Hotspot медленная работа

Tags: mikrotik, hotspot

Настраиваю Mikrotik Hotspot (RB3011UiAS + Cap2nd) + Freeradius + Captive portal.

В целом связка работает, но после авторизации на captive portal **очень медленно** открываются HTTP страницы и еще медленнее работает HTTPS.
Ресурсы из локальной сети работают быстро.
Данная проблема на физичиских портах и по беспроводной сети.
При отключении Hotspot все работает отлично как по проводу, так и без него.
Экспорт конфигурации: https://hastebin.com/zilufuxesi.sql

Подскажите что не так делаю?

Comment: каптив портал на 3011?

Comment: нет, выделенный убунту сервер. проблему решил.

Comment: я не про страничку, про `/ip hotspot`

Comment: мсс?) я угадал?

Comment: с микротика редирект на внешнюю страницу, а потом назад

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в hotspot -> user profiles - выключил пул адресов и заработало как положено.

Comment: выкинь ippool из фрирадиуса. на хотспоте он вреден

Comment: еще в /ip hotspot server пул выключи если включен

Comment: Из профиля хотспот пользователя убрал пул, в радиусе не настраивал ippool и прописывать ip в БД нет нужды, а если из профиля хотспот сервера убрать пул, то устройства перестают видеть сам хотспот, но прекрасно видят каптив портал на который их не перебрасывает, пока оставлю так.

Comment: странно. у меня вот если там стоит пул, то на каждое устройство по 2 ип выдается из него. не очень удобно.

Answer (score 0):

В большинстве случаев подстройкой `mss` решается. На некоторых версиях тупят `queues`.